# Rhythmbox restarts active session and puts on login screen

Tags: rhythmbox

I am running gnome 3.16 on ubuntu 15.04.When I try running rhythmbox it logs me out and puts me back on to my login page.

Comment: Can you post the output of `rhythmbox -d` ? I found a similar bug described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1514940) (in 2010 !) not resolved.

Comment: rhythmbox -d  still takes me back to the login page. I'm stuck !!!

Comment: have you tried to purge rhythmbox configuration and reinstall ? `sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox*`, then `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

Comment: no removing and again installing didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by gdm I reinstalled gdm which solved the problem.

To reinstall gdm i used tasksel and reinstalled the gnome desktop manager